# Internal recursion with vhost config & .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, symfony, vhosts

I'm trying to set up a web site based on symfony2. Everything is ok, but on a specific server, the way of apache vhosts are set up & the .htaccess on the symfony webroot causes infinite loop.

If someone have a clue to make it work without changing anything in symfony code (because it has to work on other servers). The only things I can modify are vhosts settings & .htaccess.

Here are the confs :

Vhosts (sub domain) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^name.domain.fr [NC]
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ /name/web/$1  [L]
```

Symfony2 .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to check to see if it's not in the /name directory already.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^name.domain.fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/name/
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ /name/$1  [L]
```

Cheers, Jeff

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just edited because the real line is `RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ /name/web/$1  [L]` and so I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/name/web/`. But it still don't work. Any clue ? Thanks

Comment: Me again :) After some tests, it's ok. Your rule was right. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem plopoz. Just thinking about that again, you may have to add some backslahes if it's part of a regular expression. \/ instead of just /